# Controller in PHP for MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, single-responsibility-principle

I am a newbie creating my MVC framework to understand the concept of the framework itself, and the use of the concept or Separation of Concern (SoC), Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), Inversion of Control (IoC), and Dependency Injection (DI) in MVC. So I wrote in a controller pseudo code as follows:

```
class myController 
{
     private $objFactory;
     private $objRequest;
     private $objView;

     function __construct($factory, $request, $view){
         $this->objFactory = $factory->make(__DIR__); // Create the controller specific factory
         $this->objRequest = $request;
         $this->objView = $view;
     }

     function upgradeUser($type){
         $objSession = $this->objFactory->makeSession(); 
         $objUserMapper = $this->factory->makeUserMapper(); // factory has the access to DAL object

         $objUser  = $factory->makeUser($objSession->getUserId(),$objUserMapper);
         $objUser->upgrade($request);

         $objUserMapper->save($objUser);

         $this->objView->show($objUser);
     }
}
```

In your opinion does this follows the SoC, SRP, IoC, and DI. Is it violating any other principle that can be caused problem when the project will grow bigger. Any comments to improve the controller is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks more like a question for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks like you're missing a lot of `$this->`, for one. Edit: ah, I just saw you said pseudo code, never mind.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks or your comments. I have added the $this-> now

Comment: IMHO having a `Factory` that instantiates objects as a dependency instead of having the dependencies explicitly stated misses the point of doing Dependency Injection.

Comment: You are using the factory like a 'Service Locator' (Anti-pattern). The constructor should (explicitly) declare all dependencies. Passing a factory or container to the controller is not correct.

Comment: @DanielO. thanks for your comments. However, as you can see this is a controller, and this is the probably the first layer of the MVC to decide which models are required to serve the request. So if I have to create all the objects (the userMaper, user, etc) then the entire logic need to be shipped to the layer above (the front controller). And even in there, we need to have a factory to instantiate the objects. So can you elaborate more to improve this, or show some other link of a good controller.

Comment: @MHRasel But where is your router? The router is between the front controller (index.php) and the controller, right? Is this still MVC? Yes of course. The next step is to put a "container" between the front controller and the Router and let the DIC do the rest. I prefer PHP-DI for that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielO. Here I am trying not to use an active object model, but a pure domain object. In this given situation, if the router had to create the $objUser domain object (taking data from the database), then the logic of data retrieval will be on the router. Router needs to deal with the request values and deploy appropriate factory for it, and so on. And the same things can happen for any other controllers. So, the router will be very fat and will be responsible for the entire project.  What do you think?

Comment: @MHRasel Maybe my explanation was not good enough. I'm not a native speaker. I think this code shows it pretty well: https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo/blob/master/web/index.php